# Display Meta Fields PHP WP

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am using the Category and Taxonomy Meta Fields [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-meta/) to create some necessary fields in the `product categories`.

When trying to display this information in php, it does not appear.

```
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
if (function_exists('get_all_wp_terms_meta'))
{ 
   print_r( get_all_wp_terms_meta($cateID) );
}
```

in page `archive-product.php`, return `Array ( )`

Comment: have checked if $cateID has got a value at all?

Comment: @Karl Yes, the value is correct. The same that appears in the url when editing in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

In file `archive-product.php` use:

```
$cateID = get_queried_object();
$return = get_field('NameField', $cateID);
```

if using a flexible field, name the layout in the field settings and use

```
if ( have_rows( 'NameItem', $cateID ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'NameItem', $cateID ) ) : the_row();
        if( get_row_layout() == 'NameLayout' ):
            echo get_sub_field('NameFiel');
         endif;
    endwhile;
else :
```